# Jenkins Shared Pipeline Library : Can I declare static variables in vars file?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Does Jenkins Shared Pipeline Library supports static variables in `vars/*. groovy` files?

## Examples

### Referencing global variables "implicitly" (doesn't work)

```
file: vars/foo.groovy
---
def functionFoo() {return "foo"}



file: vars/bar.groovy
---
def result = functionFoo()
def functionBar() {println result}


file:Jenkinsfile
---
@Library('MyLib') _
bar.functionBar()
```

This throws error:

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: result for
>   class: groovy.lang.Binding    at
>   groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)  at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:224)
>     at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$4.call(Checker.java:241)
>     at
>   org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:238)
>     at
>   com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:24)
>     at
>   com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
>   ....

### Referencing global variables "explicitly" (does work)

```
file: vars/foo.groovy
---
def functionFoo() {return "foo"}



file: vars/bar.groovy
---
def functionBar() {
    def result = functionFoo()
    println result
}


file:Jenkinsfile
---
@Library('MyLib') _
bar.functionBar()
```

## Summary

I assume that variables are either initialized in different way or simply cannot be used withing `vars/` directory the same way function can. 
Is this feature part of Groovy language? Or a limitation of Jenkins' Global Pipeline Library?

Comment: Have you tried this?

Answer (score 9):

To define a variable inside the groovy vars, rather than a function, use [groovy.transform.Field](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/transform/Field.html):

```
@groovy.transform.Field result = functionFoo()
def functionBar() {println this.result}
```

Comment: If that will work, `groovy.transform.Field`,  looks like it's a problem how Groovy deals with variables in scripts: "Variable annotation used for changing the scope of a variable within a script from being within the run method of the script to being at the class level for the script.

The annotated variable will become a private field of the script class. The type of the field will be the same as the type of the variable."

Comment: It's worth to understand Script vs Classes: https://groovy-lang.org/structure.html#_scripts_versus_classes

Comment: subquestion: where to define enums that should be visible from jenkins pipeline and so these can be passed as parameter to one of the shared library functions? src or vars?

Comment: The only 2 things I overpay for are a good Cognac and Jenkins Magic answers. Thanks.

Comment: I get CPS errors when trying to use this. Besides the error itself, it seems to cause the engine to get confused and return values too early and/or call the wrong method. I can't figure out where to put the `@NonCPS` decorator to fix it.