# Jenkins Pipeline: How do I use map in pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

My jenkins part of the pipeline content is :

```
def nodejsmap = [ "/home/tcl/customer": "sales-customer-ui-prod", "/home/tcl/platform": "sales-platform-ui-prod" ]

pipeline{
   
   agent { label "docker-slave2" }
   
   options {
       timestamps()
   }  
   
   stages {
       
       stage('parallel stage'){
           steps {
             script {
                for  (element in nodejsmap) {
                      stage('Preparation') {
                       sh 'printenv'
                       cleanWs()
                       git branch: "${env.gitlabBranch}", credentialsId: '12345678', url: 'http://172.16.200.112:8000/${element.value}.git'
                       }

   
                       stage('Build') {
                          nodejs('nodejs_16.16') {
                          sh 'npm install --location=global yarn'
                          sh 'yarn install'
                          sh 'rm -f package-lock.json'
                          sh 'npm run build:dev'
                          sh 'tar -zcvf dist/dist.tar dist/*' 
                          }
                        }
```

When I run this pipeline, it report error:
[image]

[image]

Is there a mistake in the way I use map? How should I modify the pipeline?

Comment: I haven't done Jenkins in a bit so this is a comment rather than an answer, but I would think it's the slashes in your keys.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40490105/7571258. Tl;dr: Your "global" variable isn't global, it is actually a local variable of the `run()` method of the script class. Use `@groovy.transform.Field` annotation to change its scope to become a member of the script class.

Answer (score 0):

```java
def Map mySuperMap = [ 
   mykey1:false,
   mykey2:"some string",
   some_key: 123
]
print(mySuperMap.some_key)
```

keys must be just keys. if u need more variables - add more keys

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**